# Echoing text until a key is pressed

Tags: batch-file

I have a FOR loop who read a TXT file. And echo it line after line evry 2 seconds (ping method). And i want to go out from this loop when the user press a key (i need the keyvalue too).

Here is my code :

```
@echo ofF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%i IN (test.txt) DO ECHO %%i>x&FOR %%z IN (x) DO (cls&set /a length=%%~zz-1&del x&set $f=
                                                                                         for /l %%a in (0,1,!length!) do (set $f=Í!$f!)
                                                                                         echo É!$f!»&echo º %%i º&echo È!$f!¼
                                                                                         echo.&echo PRESS 1 - TO CONTINUE&PRESS X - TO ABORT
                                                                                         ping localhost -n 2 > NUL)
```

I need to go out when a key is pressed
The file test.txt look like this :

Thanks and sorry for my bad english

Comment: this can be done with `CHOICE` but it accepts only numbers and letters...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please share your code or explain what you have tried. If you read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) you will realize we aren't here to do your job/homework, only assist in your problems.

Comment: You can't do that without any external programs.

Comment: Have you considered writing a [powershell script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/powershell.aspx)?

Comment: I'm trying to do it in batch, eventually with an external command. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will detect pressed numbers and letters.The **0** is the default pressed key so it will be not detected.That's the best I can achieve with a batch file.

```
@echo off

rem ---- set the path to your file here ----
set "file=file"

echo press a key to stop the print
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=*" %%L in ("%file%") do (
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    (echo(%%L)
    endlocal
    CHOICE /C abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 /cs  /D 0 /T 2 >nul
    if  not errorlevel 62 goto :endfor
)

:endfor

set /a choosen=%errorlevel%
color
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a counter=1
for %%# in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ) do (

    if !counter! NEQ %choosen% (
        set /a counter=!counter!+1
    ) else (
        set pressed=%%# & goto :endfor2
    )
)
:endfor2 
endlocal & set pressed=%pressed%
echo pressed button - %pressed%
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the same npocmaka's code, but slightly modified:

```
@echo off

rem ---- set the value of your file here ----
set "file=D:\my file"

set options=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%file%") do (
    echo %%L
    CHOICE /C %options% /cs  /D 0 /T 2 >nul
    if errorlevel 2 goto :endfor
)
:endfor
set /A choosen=%errorlevel%-1
color
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set pressed=!options:~%choosen%,1!
endlocal & set pressed=%pressed%
echo %pressed%
```

Comment: clever.One for loop less :)

Comment: empty lines and lines containing `!` will be not displayed correctly.print the lines like this : `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    (echo(%%L)
 endlocal`  . Jeb showed me this here : http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1707

Comment: @npocmaka - The lines will ECHO just fine since delayed expansion is not enabled while in the loop.